# Why is this compdef error message referring to?

Tags: shell, terminal, zshrc

I've recently switched over to zshrc and every time I load up my terminal, I get this error message:

```
Last login: Tue Nov 26 12:20:36 on ttys000
complete:13: command not found: compdef
complete:13: command not found: compdef
```

I looked for other answers/solutions and some posts have hinted at something in the .zshrc file; mine looks like this:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"

PATH="/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/9.4/bin:$PATH"

export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && . "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion
```

Just in case, I also checked my .zprofile file, but it only has this line in it:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

One of the posts that I came across hinted that the problem was in the export NVM section of the .zshrc file, however, I'm not sure how to resolve this. There was one solution that referenced the placement/order of the export NVM.. block in the .zshrc file; am i missing something or have I misplaced/incorrectly ordered something in my .zshrc file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is calling `complete`, but `compdef` is defined by `compinit`, so you need to call that first.

```
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit

# Now you can write code that calls compdef
```

If you run `compinstall`, it will add the necessary lines to your `.zshrc` for you.

Comment: I'm guessing that this would need to be written in the .zshrc file?